# Python: Trying to get index of an intersection

Tags: python, indexing, set-intersection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Finding corresponding indices for an intersection of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570417/python-finding-corresponding-indices-for-an-intersection-of-two-lists)

I have the following line of code:

```
for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(catdate) if x == set(NNSRCfile['datetimenew']).intersection(catdate)]:
    print i
```

I am trying to find the index of the intersection for the two components above. Both are lengthy lists that have several commonalities. The intersection part works perfectly; however, the for loop seems to output nothing. (ie: there is nothing that is printed).

Python outputs no error, and when I run the code in IPython, I notice that i is equivalent to to the very last element in the list "catdate", instead of listing the indices of "catdate" that are equivalent to the intersection values.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this different from your post yesterday?

Comment: Yes, it is, though it is the same problem. I am trying a different approach though.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use `x in ...` to test if `x` is in your intersection ?

Comment: @Pierre, do you mean using "x in" instead of "x ==" ?

Comment: You know the .intersection doesnt (logically) do anything since we know x is in catdate you need only test if x is in set(NNSRCfile['datetimenew']).   Precomputing the intersection might be more efficient though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test whether `x` is in your intersection, you should use:

```
indices = [i for (i, x) in enumerate(catdate) if x in set(NNSRCfile['datetimenew']).intersection(catdate)]
for i in indices:
    print i
```

Otherwise, you're comparing a single element to a set, which is unlikely to work (therefore, the test always fail, your `indices` list is empty, nothing gets printed...

Comment: I think that solved my problem. I didn't know you could you "if... in..."
Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: @user1620716 Glad to help. Practice makes perfect, keep going!

Answer (score 0):

set() will not match a single value, try:

```
if set(x) == set( ...
```

Personally I'd avoid using the same "i" in nested contexts like that, btw, although python alloqws it. At least it is confusing to read..